# How to separate a value from a class

Tags: javascript

I want to attempt to get a value from a site and calculate it.

At the moment when entering the command
`document.getElementById("txtTehtav")`
I recieve the answer along the lines of
`<a class="thrida" id="txtTehtav" name="txtTehtav">3x3=</a>`
My goal would be to separate the value (3x3) into X and Y (X x Y)
How would I be able to accomplish that?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: do you mean you want to seperate it to become 3 multiply 3?

Comment: `let [x, y]= document.getElementById("txtTehtav").textContent.match(/\d+/g);` assigns the numbers in the text to `x` and `y`. It's notable, the values are strings, you should convert them to numbers before doing math with the variables. This works only if there's at least one number in the string, otherwise it throws an error.

Answer (score 3):

```
    const textValue = document.getElementById("txtTehtav").innerText; // Will return 3x3=
    const [x, y] = textValue.substr(0, textValue.length - 1).split('x').map((n) => parseInt(n))

const muliplication = x*y;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you will get the text

```
document.getElementById("txtTehtav").textContent
```