# How do I make my code rerun/change when a certain element's value changes in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In my case I run the code

```
var a = document.getElementById("txtTehtav").textContent.match(/\d+/g)
let [x, y] = a
var answer = x*y
alert(answer)
```

The element which I would like to watch is txtTehtav.
The code for the element is `<a class="thrida" id="txtTehtav" name="txtTehtav">3x4=</a>`
So whenever the textContent of txtTehtav changes (in this case 3x4) I want my code to rerun/update so x and y would change, where as 3 would be x and 4 would be y.
(for example my code would give the answer for 3x4 and when it will change to something like 2x4 my code would detect it and rerun it/update the answer)

How do I make my code rerun when that happens?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the code that is changing the text content. putting your code there would be the easiest way.

Comment: Why would the text content of an anchor change? Who's changing it? When does it change?

Comment: Not exactly related, but you don't have to create a new account for [every question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67211180/1169519) ...

Comment: Also you don't need `name` attributes for `a` elements

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your setup:

1. If you know which code changes the text content of your DOM element, you can adjust it to call your function or listen to any events that code might trigger.
2. If you don't, you can use `MutationObserver` to listen for DOM changes. [Read more about them on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver)